# Rails accessing an instance variable from a different view controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

im having trouble with my application and i've exhausted all my attempts to get a solution. My problem is: i have a controller with an instance variable called compositions and i have another controller for my static pages and i want to pass compositions variable to my index. How can i do it?

**Heroku Error**

```html
2017-01-30T03:37:03.434514+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
2017-01-30T03:37:03.435598+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5]     16: 
2017-01-30T03:37:03.435601+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5]     17: <div class="panel-container">
2017-01-30T03:37:03.435602+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5]     18: 
2017-01-30T03:37:03.435603+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5]     19:   <% @compositions.each do |composition| %>
2017-01-30T03:37:03.435604+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5]     20:       <div class="panel player">
2017-01-30T03:37:03.435604+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5]     21:         <div class="panel-top player-top">
2017-01-30T03:37:03.435605+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5]     22:           <div class="row">
2017-01-30T03:37:03.435633+00:00 app[web.1]: [14a3c747-4c38-4392-b5d4-63bc0379b7e5]
```

**compositions_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @compositions = Composition.all.order('created_at desc')
end
```

**static_pages/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="panel-container">
<% @compositions.limit(4).each do |composition| %>
  <div class="panel player">
    <div class="panel-top player-top">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="panel-title"><%= composition.title %></p><span class="icon-dots-three-horizontal"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row user-details">
        <p>Projeto por <%= composition.user.username %></p><a href="#" class="ui-btn btn-small"><span class="icon-export"></span>visitar
        perfil</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-bottom player-controls">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col30">
          <p><span class="icon-controller-play"></span><%= composition.plays %></p>
          <p><span class="icon-note"></span>230</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col30"><span class="controllers"><span class="icon-controller-play"></span>
            <p>2:15 / 430</p></span></div>
        <div class="col30">
          <p><span class="icon-chat"></span>23</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `@compositions` again in your `static_pages_controller#index`

Comment: "NameError (uninitialized constant StaticPagesController::Composition)" Ahhhhhhhh what is wrong? xD `def index
    @compositions = Composition.all.order('created_at desc').limit(4)
  end`

Comment: Is this `StaticPagesController` from a gem?

Comment: No its from my app's controllers folder

Comment: Are you sure you have `Composition` class/model?

Comment: Yes i have. Right on my models folder

Comment: Can you post error trace from local instead of Heroku?

Comment: Lol xD for some reason i havent pushed my git commit. Sorry for this trouble and thanks.